# create Horizontal sub menu with css

Tags: html, css

I want to create a horizontal sub menu when hover on main menu like this

But this is what I have made

How do I resolve this problem?

[create this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruGTr.png)

but i want this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTz8d.png)

/**********************************************************************/

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#iri-header {
    font-family: 'Iranian Sans';
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.142;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    width: 1349px;
    height: 40.5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

#orb-header {
    position: relative;
}

.iri-header-container {
    width: 1008px;
    height: 39.5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0 16px;
}

.logo {
    width: 96px;
    height: 39.5px;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    float: right;
}

    .logo img {
        float: right;
        padding-top: 8px;
    }

.loging {
    width: 197.5px;
    height: 39.5px;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}

    .loging:hover {
        border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    }

#vorod {
    float: right;
    padding: 12px;
}

.loging img {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}

.search {
    width: 300px;
    height: 39.5px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.Search {
    width: 45px;
    height: 39.5px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

    .Search img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

.brand {
    width: 1349px;
    height: 95px;
    background-color: #BB1919;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.site-brand {
    width: 976px;
    height: 59px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.brand .site-brand a > span {
    float: right;
    font-family: A Ketab;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu {
    width: 1349px;
    height: 36px;
}

.menu-container {
    width: 1349px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #A91717;
}

.menu-ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 35px;
}

#main_menu {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 93px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

    #main_menu li {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }

        #main_menu li a {
            display: block;
            padding: 10px; /* For example */
            position: relative;
        }

li a {
    display: inline-block; /* To enable padding */
    padding: 10px; /* For example */
}

li:not(:hover) .submenu {
    display: none;
}

li:hover .submenu {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0; /* If you want to stick it to the left edge, remove this line. */
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#main_menu li:hover {
    background-color: #eb4b4b;
}

#main_menu li ul {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #820e0e;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
    display: none;
    direction: rtl;
    margin-right: 60px;
}

#main_menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

#main_menu li ul li {
    float: left;
    direction: rtl;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #BB4545;
    display: block;
}

    #main_menu li ul li a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
    }

li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>سایت IRI</title>
    <link href="~/Content/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme-rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <div>
      <header id="iri-header">
        <div id="orb-header">
          <div class="iri-header-container">
            <div class="logo">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="~/Content/img/Logo.png" />
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="loging">
              <a href="/Home/Register">
                <div class="loging-container">

                  <span id="vorod">ورود/ثبت نام</span>

                  <img src="~/Content/img/pic1.png" />
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="search">
              @Html.Partial("P_Search")
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="brand">
        <div class="site-brand">
          <a href="/Home/Index">
            <span>اخبار ایران و جهان</span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
          <div class="menu-container">
            <div class="menu-ul">
              <ul id="main_menu">
                <li><a href="#">1صفحه اصلی</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">صفحه اصلی2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3صفحه اصلی</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">4صفحه اصلی</a></li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">صفحه اصلی5</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">صفحه اصلی</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">صفحه اصلی</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">صفحه اصلی</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">صفحه اصلی</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">صفحه اصلی6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">7صفحه اصلی</a></li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">8صفحه اصلی</a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">صفحه اصلی</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">صفحه اصلی</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">صفحه اصلی</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">صفحه اصلی</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">صفحه اصلی9</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">10صفحه اصلی</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">صفحه اصلی11</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?
http://codepen.io/bra1N/pen/yJwZWo

This code is important:

```
#main_menu li {
    float: right;
    border-left: 1px solid #BB4545;
    position: static;
}
#main_menu li ul {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #820e0e;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 110px;
    float: left;
    display: none;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Comment: yse . thanks . but see the pic in my question . edit

Answer (score 0):

This code should make `.submenu` appear only if `a` is hovered.

```
/* Reset */
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Important part */

li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block; /* To enable padding */
    padding: 10px; /* For example */
}

li:not(:hover) .submenu {
    display: none;
}

li:hover .submenu {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0; /* If you want to stick it to the left edge, remove this line. */
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**DEMO:**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dXArNx

Comment: Thank you for taking the time for my question . but it vetical

Comment: Check it now, should be correct (it's horizontal yet).

Comment: my problem is : when hover the main li . sub menu vary much margin right

and create scroll

Comment: for my project is vertical. :(

Comment: than you have some css that overriding mine